# Changing values of elements in view in MVC using jquery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a label

```
@Html.Label("GetCheckboxDetail", new { @style = "display:none" , id = "CheckboxDetailFlag" , name = "GetCheckboxDetail" })
```

In javascript i am trying to change it

```
$(".LRequiredClass").live("click", function (event) {
    if ($(".LRequiredClass").is(":checked")) {
        $("#CheckboxDetailFlag").val("LRequired True"); 
        }
        else {
        $("#CheckboxDetailFlag").val("LRequired False"); 
        }
});
```

and in controller `Request["GetCheckboxDetail"]` is returning null, even after the value is changed in label

Comment: what jquery version you used?

Comment: 1.8.3, if i give alert there, it is coming, but the values are not getting changed

Comment: shouldn't it be `.text()` for a label?

Comment: A label does not have a value - it needs to be `$("#CheckboxDetailFlag").text(..)` and why on earth are you giving it a name attribute

Comment: ya sorry text changes values, i am not able get that in controller

Comment: @StephenMuecke name is for accessing it from controller

Comment: A label is not a control. It does not post anything (and I suspect you don't even have an associated control named `GetCheckboxDetail` so its not really a label anyway). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @vignesh, You need to store this text in an `hidden` field or something else.

Comment: @vignesh, Please roll back your edit. The answers and comments now don't make sense.

Comment: @Manoz Ya manoz thought of storing it in a hidden label. Changed it to textbox and it worked

Comment: @StephenMuecke done, identified the problem

Answer (score 2):

use `.text()` instead of `.val()`. you change the value text for label so use `text()`

```
$("#CheckboxDetailFlag").text("LRequired True");
```

actually the code be

```
if ($(".LRequiredClass").is(":checked")) {
    $("#CheckboxDetailFlag").text("LRequired True"); 
    }
    else {
    $("#CheckboxDetailFlag").text("LRequired False"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue

I made the following changes

**VIEW**

```
@Html.Text("GetCheckboxDetail", new { @style = "display:none" , id = "CheckboxDetailFlag" , name = "GetCheckboxDetail" })
```

Javascript and controller code remained the same and controller was able to get data from textbox.

Comment: Just use `@Html.Hidden("GetCheckboxDetail")` and change the script to `$("#GetCheckboxDetail").val(...)` (or better `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GetCheckboxDetail)` assuming its a model property)